# When I archive a row in another sheet in Google Sheets, it's deleting this row and the next one from the source sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, row, archive

**My goal:** by ticking a checkbox, I want to archive an entire row from source sheet (Leads) to the target sheet (Archive), same to unarchive from the target to the source sheet. I'm using this code for +1 year and never faced the kind of issue I'm having.

**1st issue:** When I tick the box for row X in the source sheet:

1. It's deleting the row X and row Y from the source sheet
2. Just row Y is moved and stored to the target sheet -> I don't know where row X goes.

**2nd issue:** When I try to unarchive row Y (even if it should be row X), nothing happens.

**My code is:**

```
      // Variables defined in an onEdit(event) function
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
      var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

      // Archive a project with checked box to Archive Sheet
    if(s.getName() == "Leads" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == true) { 
      var row = r.getRow();
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      s.deleteRow(row);
      } 
      
      // Unarchive a project from Archive sheet to respective owner
    if(s.getName() == "Archive" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == false) {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Leads");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
```

I tried to debug the code but I can't find my mistake.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: I tried to use the copyTo method and keep the deleteRow and in a second time, to use only the moveTo method, but I have exactly the same issues...

Comment: I actually dont see any issue in the code. tested the code above with sample data and it doesnt delete rows other than the ticked row. moveTo moves the data but the actual row isn't deleted. so I assume you want to adjust the rows so it doesnt show any blank rows after moving the data which is actually right. Same goes to unarchiving/vice versa. Can you try the same code with a new sheet? Also, take note that you need to slow down the ticking/unticking of checkboxes as that might also be the cause why other rows when ticked are not being processed properly.

Comment: Thanks Nazia for your help. Actually I'm using this code for other files and I never had any issues... I don't understand why I'm facing - I've commented some parts of the code to see if something was wrong with the rest of the code and I'm still struggling with the 2 issues I presented. I think I'm going to create a new file and redo the step by step the code.